# Javafx MediaPlayer runs into error whenever you disconnect bluetooth headphones

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I have a highschool capstone where I must create a music player which plays music. However, whenever I connect my bluetooth headphones(airpods or musicozy) and then disconnect them, the MediaPlayer halts and an error is produced. I've searched on the internet for an answer but am unable to find one. If someone could help me that would be great! I'm using Javafx 17.0.2 and JDK 11.

Here's a mini reproducible example below.

## JavaFxMediaPlayer

```
package apprunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFxMediaPlayer extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("My");
        Button button = new Button("Play Song");
        Scene scene = new Scene(button, 200, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\John Doe\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\YourLieInAprilTest\\Mp3Test.mp3");
        String path = file.toURI().toASCIIString();
        Media media = new Media(path);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        });
        Runnable printStackTrace = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer.getError().getMessage();
                mediaPlayer.getError().printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        mediaPlayer.setOnError(printStackTrace);

    }
}
```

## module-info

```
module MotisHarmony {
    requires javafx.swt;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.web;
    exports mediaplayerjavafx;
    opens mediaplayerjavafx to javafx.graphics;
}
```

## Error Produced

```
MediaException: PLAYBACK_HALTED : IDirectSoundBuffer_GetStatus The operation completed successfully.
, IDirectSoundBuffer_GetCurrentPosition: The operation completed successfully.
, dwStatus: 0
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.haltException(MediaException.java:150)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$_PlayerStateListener.lambda$onHalt$7(MediaPlayer.java:2566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

## New JavaFxMediaPlayer Fix Attempt (Seek not working)

```
package apprunner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AppRunner extends Application {

    public Duration durationBackup = null;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("My");
        Button button = new Button("Play Song");
        Scene scene = new Scene(button, 200, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\John Doe\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\YourLieInAprilTest\\Mp3Test.mp3");
        String path = file.toURI().toASCIIString();
        Media media = new Media(path);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                //Here we keep a backup of the current duration of the song just incase the mediaPlayer crashes, which it does everytime you disconnect a bluetooth headset for some reason
                durationBackup = mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime();
            }
        });
        //Here I try to create a new MediaPlayer and go to the last position we were at before the mediaPlayer halted
        Runnable attemptToResetMediaPlayer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                mediaPlayer.play();
                System.out.println(durationBackup.toMillis());
                mediaPlayer.seek(durationBackup);
            }
        };
        mediaPlayer.setOnError(attemptToResetMediaPlayer);
    }
}
```

### How to recreate bug

- First you must connect your bluetooth headphones to your laptop/computer
- Then you must run the mini reproducible example above
- Then you must click on the "Play Song" button which appears
- Then when the song is playing, disconnect your bluetooth headphones
- The mediaPlayer will halt and the error message and its stack trace will be printed

## Extra Information

> Link to the Mp3 file I used to test. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CvAafbMviQ7nvKyojnem9GK73LJsD6MJ/view?usp=sharing

> I am using JDK 11 and Javafx 17.0.2

> System Type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

> Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz 2.81 GHz

> Windows Edition: Windows 10 Home

Comment: It is worth trying with JavaFX 18.  Perhaps this  particular problem may have been fixed (indirectly) by https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8253351

Comment: @swpalmer Hi, I went ahead and tested the program with Javafx 18 and Javafx 19-ea+4. The problem was not fixed, the error remains the same. Thanks for your suggestion tho!

Comment: Time to file a bug against JavaFX then. I assume other media players don't stop when you disconnect the bluetooth headphones?

Comment: @swpalmer I think they do stop, the sound stops playing and the status of the MediaPlayer is set to "Halted".

Comment: Then perhaps it isn't a bug exactly and you will have to work around it by manually restarting when you detect it is halted.

Comment: @swpalmer Okay, I've attempted to fix the problem by creating a backup of the Duration before the musicPlayer crashes. For whatever reason, when I create the new MusicPlayer and then try to seek to the durationBackup, the MusicPlayer which I create still starts from the beginning! I cannot find out why. I have added my new code above in the section "New JavaFxMediaPlayer Fix Attempt (Seek not working)".

Comment: Perhaps try mediaPlayer.setStartTime(Duration) instead?

Comment: @swpalmer Hi, I went ahead and tried that. It worked great until I realized that by setting the StartTime of the mediaPlayer you also change the total duration. For example, if you have a 2 hour song, and you set the StartTime to 1 hr, if you were to use the .getTotalDuration() on the MediaPlayer object it would return 1hr rather than 2hrs. This in return also prevents me from going back to the beginning of the song too which won't work for me. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @swpalmer I tried using the .setOnReady() method to seek to my durationBackup, but it still just played the song from the beginning instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243802/discussion-between-swpalmer-and-harharprogrammer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your recovery is that you are seeking too soon. The docs for seek state that it does nothing while the media player is stopped, but you aren't waiting for the state to change after calling play().

Try this:

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnError( () -> {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            System.out.println(durationBackup.toMillis());
            mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(() ->{
                mediaPlayer.seek(durationBackup);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPlaying(null);
            });
            mediaPlayer.play();
    });
```